# jQuery add class if nothing selected

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery script which selects (highlights) and deselects divs based on the item that is clicked...

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $links = $('.property');
    $links.click(function(e) {
        //Get our variables, simply $(this) and the colour
        var $this = $(this),
            color = $this.data('col');

        //Toggle the active class on this link
        $this.toggleClass('active');

        //Remove .main on all .test's
        $(".slayout").removeClass("main");
        $(".product").addClass("trans");
        $(".product").removeClass("main");

        //Map the active link's data-col with a dot attributes to an array
        //Join it up to make a selector
        var selector = $links.filter('.active').map(function(){
            return "."+$(this).data('col');
        }).get().join('');

        //Add the class back on to matches
        $(selector).addClass('main');

        //Finally, prevent the default action
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

How can I modify this so that if no items are selected then a new CSS class is applied to all items.  This class should be removed if anything is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

You can test if you have one or more `$(selector)` :

```
var selector = $links.filter('.active').map(function(){
    return "."+$(this).data('col');
}).get().join('');

// remove the class added when there was no item selected
$('.allitems').removeClass('myclass');

if ($(selector).length > 0) {
    //Add the class back on to matches
    $(selector).addClass('main');
} else {
    $('.allitems').addClass('myclass');
}
```

Comment: This adds myclass correctly, but when I then select another item so that the selector length is no longer 0 it doesn't remove myclass and keeps it in

Answer (score 0):

```
if (selector.length == 0)
  // add class to all items
```

Just do not make .join() before it, or $(selector).length if join is done.